# The difference between permutation and composition in the subject of probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

In general we have:
$$\dfrac{p(k,r)}{p(n,r)}=\dfrac{c(k,r)}{c(n,r)}$$
is it different or same in the topic of probability to solve the question by permutation or combination?

For example, from 5 green beads and 4 blue beads, we choose 3 beads.
What is the probability that all three beads are blue?

However, the permutation method and the combination of the answer are the same.

$P(A)=\dfrac{p(4,3)}{p(9,3)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{4!}{1!}}{\dfrac{9!}{6!}}=\dfrac{1}{21} ....... and......P(A)=\dfrac{c(4,3)}{c(9,3)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{4!}{1!\times3!}}{\dfrac{9!}{6!\times3!}}=\dfrac{1}{21}$

Thank you. I apologize for my poor English writing.

Comment: It does not matter whether you use permutations or combinations for a problem like this, as you have correctly shown for this example, so long as whichever you choose to use *you remain consistent with that choice* for both the numerator *and* denominator.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thank you. Is there an example where the answer is different in permutation and combination mode?

Comment: "*What is the probability that the first bead is blue and the second two are green*"  In this case since we specifically referring to the order in which beads are being selected, we have to keep track of the order.